# 24 Hour Clock to Hours and Minutes

Tags: c++, time

I'm having some trouble with this, and just wondering if anyone can help. I'm new to all this, and getting the correct value for minutes is really bothering me. If I were to put in 1850 as a departure time, and 1900 as the arrival time, it should be ten minutes, but instead it's 50 due to it being an integer. Any advice?

> Question:
> Write a program that will ask the user to enter the departure time and arrival time for a train journey. The times should be entered as per a 24-hour clock, for example quarter to seven in the evening is 1845. Assuming that the journey is within the same 24-hour period, the program should calculate and display the duration of the journey in hours and minutes.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int diff, mins, hours, arrTime, depTime;
    
    cout << "\nDeparture: ";
    cin >> depTime;
    cout << "\nArrival: ";
    cin >> arrTime;
    
    diff = arrTime - depTime;
    hours = diff / 100;
    mins = diff % 100;
    
    if(mins > 60){
        hours++;
        mins -= 60;
    }

    cout << "Hours: " << hours << " Minutes: " << Minutes;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can store the hours and minutes separately and use modulus 12 with hours and modulus 60 with minutes.

Comment: It may be easier to convert everything to seconds. Also do not forget about corner-cases when the first time point is before 24:00 and the second is after 00:00 like 23:00 - 03:00

Comment: @elo Easiest is to use std::chrono's timepoint and duration types from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono.  All the nastiness with the corner cases day/month/year/leap year stuff has been taken care of, and has been tested.